# Rendering DataTable with php from JSON & MySQL Data

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I am rendering a DataTable with php, getting the data from a MySQL-Database.

The table get rendered, but the are columns in the table, which contain links of images (4th column) or links to other websites (on the 6th column). How can I render the links of the images, as images directly? And the links of the websites, as an Hypertext-Link not a text?

**Here is my jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#oShopTab').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url :"aPage-data.php", // json datasource
            type: "post"
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="oShopTab" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>pId</th>
            <th>sName</th>
            <th>lName</th>
            <th>logo Link</th>
            <th>Incentiv</th>
            <th>Go To Shop URL..</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>pId</th>
            <th>sName</th>
            <th>lName</th>
            <th>logo Link</th>
            <th>Incentiv</th>
            <th>Go To Shop URL..</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: `<img src="<?= $the_image_link; ?>" />` and `<a href="<?= $the_site_url ?>">Website</a>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3749664/4942980