# How to input links to tables in DataTables javascript plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am looking to dynamically add hyperlinks to a DataTable table fields while pulling the tables data from a .txt file. Is there a way to do this or am I missing something?

The DataTables docs are at: [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

Here is my code and .txt data so far:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Column [render functions](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) can help with that - go to the example section and look at the 4th example. Also see [I want to create links in record fields in DataTables from JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748262/i-want-to-create-links-in-record-fields-in-datatables-from-json-data). There are various approaches presented there, including the column render function. If none of those meet your needs, maybe you can clarify with a specific example?

Comment: That's perfect. Fourth example worked like a charm! Thanks Guy.

Answer (score 0):

Column render functions can help with that - go to the example section and look at the 4th example. Also see I want to create links in record fields in DataTables from JSON data. There are various approaches presented there, including the column render function. If none of those meet your needs, maybe you can clarify with a specific example? – andrewjames